# Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() causing a ton of errors

Tags: c#, rigid-bodies, unity-game-engine

I am trying to follow the space shooter tutorial online with unity5 and i am having trouble with rigidbody.

I realize that rigidbody has been replaced with Component.GetComponent() but i want to make a variable instead of typing this all out.

I am getting a TON of errors using Component.GetComponent() and dont understand what's wrong.

Here is my code snippet, i am trying to constrain the movement with clamp:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float xMin, zMin, xMax, zMax;

    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement*speed;

        Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3
        (
            Mathf.Clamp(Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.x, xMin, xMax),
            0.0f,
            Mathf.Clamp(Component.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.z, zMin, zMax)
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the spitload of errors it gives me:

```
Finished updating scripts / assemblies

Some scripts have compilation errors which may prevent obsolete API usages to get updated. Obsolete API updating will continue automatically after these errors get fixed.

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(14,27): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)'

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(14,47): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)'

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(18,31): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Mathf.Clamp(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(18,31): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(20,47): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)'

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(20,31): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Mathf.Clamp(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(20,31): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(21,18): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(21,18): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'

Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(16,27): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)'
```

I feel like im missing something important and obvious because this isn't a lot of code to warrant so many errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create an instance of an object before using non-static class functions.

In your case it most likely will be gameObject which have RigidBody component attached. Here is code example:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>().velocity = movement * speed;
```

Redo other strings in your code respectively.

Comment: This works, I also found that this.gameObject.GetComponent and this.GetComponent works.

Comment: Also just GetComponent

Comment: Aslo as you are using same `RigidBody` in several places it would be nicely if you will create a variable containing this component. So use `RigidBody rb = gameObjcet.GetComponent<RigidBody>()` or one of your examples of getting it, and then every time you want to interact with this component you use `rb` instead of `GetComponent<RigidBody>()`.

For example `rb.velocity = movement * speed`.